# How to authenticate and authorize uses of my python web app using Azure AD?

Tags: python, azure, flask, azure-active-directory

I have a python/Flask application, on our intranet, and I want people to authenticate to it using their Azure AD credentials. Pretty much every hit on Google/Bing/etc is about how to use AD to authenticate so you can subsequently use Microsoft APIs, such as Graph or Data Lake, or they are for .NET applications, or they are for stuff running on the Azure cloud.

The closest I've come to what I need is https://github.com/cicorias/python-flask-aad-v2, and the instructions refer to some older version of Azure. It would also be nice if I could specify whether an authenticated user should have access to this app, but I can live without it and simply have a list of allowed IDs in the app's back-end.

This cannot be that hard; I've done this in the past for both GCP and AWS, but I've hit the proverbial brick wall  when it came to Azure. While this is not my first overall rodeo, it is my first Azure/AD rodeo, so to speak. I'm sure that part of my problem is that, being an Azure noob, I may not even be using the right search keywords.

Help?

Answer (score 0):

Do not think in terms of the providers but in terms of the Authentication standards. Since you have integrated Google Login in your app in the past then you must have used something called OAuth as the auth standard. [Azure AD also supports OAuth](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v1-protocols-oauth-code). You can use a python package called [flask-azure-oauth](https://github.com/antarctica/flask-azure-oauth) to integrate it in your flask app.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to below code samples available in Microsoft Identity Platform documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/sample-v2-code#web-applications)

- Sign in users - https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-python-flask-tutorial
- Sign in users and call Microsoft Graph - https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-python-webapp

These links are for Python (Flask). You can get code samples for other languages or scenario from Microsoft Identity Platform documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/sample-v2-code#web-applications)